# Slick/Scala - how do I access fields of the mapped projection/projected table part of a join in a where query

Tags: scala, join, where-clause, slick

I have a number of basic queries define, and am using query composition to add stuff such as ordering, paging, where clauses and so on...

But I have a problem accessing the fields of the joined 2nd table in the where clause...

Here's my table queries and my table. All tables are mapped to case classes.

```
val basicCars = TableQuery[CarTable]
val basicCarValues = TableQuery[CarValueTable]

val carsWithValues = for {
    (c, v) <- basicCars leftJoin basicCarValues on (_.id === _.carId)
} yield (c, v.?)
```

Now I reuse/compose queries by doing stuff such as

```
carsWithValues.where(_._1.id === someId)
```

which works perfectly...

But if I want to access any value of the 2nd table... and I try

```
carsWithValues.where(_._2.latestPrice === somePrice)
```

It tells me that `somePrice` is not a member of `MappedProjection`......

> error: value somePrice is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.MappedProjection[Option[com......datastore.slick.generated.Tables.CarValue],(Option[Long], Option[Long], Option[String],.....

I understand that this kind of can't work, cause _._2 is a MappedProjection and not just a CarValue sitting in the tuple..

But I can't figure out how to use any field of the table that is in the MappedProjection in a where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.?` from the Slick code generator is implemented using a MappedProjection, which doesn't have the members anymore. If you postpone the call to `.?` it works:

```
val carsWithValues = for {
    (c, v) <- basicCars leftJoin basicCarValues on (_.id === _.carId)
} yield (c, v)

carsWithValues.where(_._2.latestPrice === somePrice).map{ case (c,v) => (c,v.?) }
```

Comment: by the way. where is going to be deprecated. Use filter instead.